# OutOfMemoryException in Windows Phone 7.1

Tags: windows, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone-8

I'm getting an `OutOfMemoryException` in my WP7.1 app. Here is the stacktrace:

> at System.String.ReplaceOrdinal(String oldValue, String newValue) 
>   at System.String.Replace(String oldValue, String newValue) at
>   A_Contacts.ContactSync.ProcessDataFirstTime(APhone p) at
>   A_Contacts.ContactSync.ContactsOnSearchCompletedFirstTime(IEnumerable`1 t) at A_Contacts.ContactSync.Contacts_SearchCompleted2(Object sender,
>   ContactsSearchEventArgs e) at
>   Microsoft.Phone.UserData.Contacts.OnSearchCompleted(Object e) at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InternalInvoke(RuntimeMethodInfo
>   rtmi, Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object
>   parameters, CultureInfo culture, Boolean isBinderDefault, Assembly
>   caller, Boolean verifyAccess, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) at
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InternalInvoke(Object obj,
>   BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters,
>   CultureInfo culture, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) at
>   System.Reflection.MethodBase.Invoke(Object obj, Object[] parameters)
>   at System.Delegate.DynamicInvokeOne(Object[] args) at
>   System.MulticastDelegate.DynamicInvokeImpl(Object[] args) at
>   System.Delegate.DynamicInvoke(Object[] args) at
>   System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke() at
>   System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.Dispatch(DispatcherPriority
>   priority) at System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.OnInvoke(Object
>   context) at System.Windows.Hosting.CallbackCookie.Invoke(Object[]
>   args) at
>   System.Windows.Hosting.DelegateWrapper.InternalInvoke(Object[] args)
>   at System.Windows.RuntimeHost.ManagedHost.InvokeDelegate(IntPtr
>   pHandle, Int32 nParamCount, ScriptParam[] pParams, ScriptParam&
>   pResult)

Comment: Generally this error is the result of a memory leak somewhere in your application, but that would be nearly impossible to find with just a stack trace. We'd probably need to see the code in A_Contacts.ContactSync.

Comment: Could you please provide more information? Please showing the portion of the code where this happens can be helpful. How lengthy are the string values, is the call on a loop, etc...

Comment: this was during insertion of data, where the existing record were being replaced by new one (update process)

Comment: dont understand why someone is giving -ve points to this question ?\

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Brian, I did the same and after lot of research I found that the Code First Database table was not formed correctly; as on the attribute it was mentioned allow NULL but as of the property was not NULLable.